# Switch not working in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, switch-statement, string-literals

I came across very strange problem today. Lets concider the following code:

```
int llex(){
    cout<<"enter 1"<<endl;
    char32_t c = U'(';
    cout<<(c==U'#')<<endl;
    switch(c){
    case U'#':
        cout<<"enter 2"<<endl;
        return 5;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout<<"enter 1"<<endl;
    char32_t c = U'(';
    cout<<(c==U'#')<<endl;
    switch(c){
    case U'#':
        cout<<"enter 2"<<endl;
        return 5;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cout << "------------" << endl;
    llex();
}
```

And the output is:

```
enter 1
0
------------
enter 1
0
enter 2
```

Please note that the code in main is IDENTICAL to the code in `llex` function. Why they output different results? (I'm using C++11 on clang).

Comment: There's a bracket missing from `llex`. Are you sure everything else is correct?

Comment: The behaviour is undefined as `llex()` does not return an `int`.

Comment: I would remove the `return 5;` from main.

Comment: @sftrabbit But that is probably not the issue, since the jump labels are not affected, only the following code. It is probably c&p mistake.

Comment: Why do people keep upvoting this? The program is malformed.

Comment: because UB is awesome

Comment: @rioki Once there's UB, literally *anything* can happen. And (especially) optimisers sometimes do indeed cause *anything* to happen.

Comment: @Angew Like, for example, supposing that the case won't occur, and suppressing it from the code.  In other words, the compiler knows that the `default` case cannot occur (because that would result in undefined behavior), and since there's only one other case, generates it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yup, those were my thoughts as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `llex()` function is supposed to always return a value, but it does not. This is **undefined behavior** if control flow does not hit the `return` statement. Per paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 standard:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; **this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function**.

Unless you fix this, you cannot make any assumptions on your program, nor have expectations about it.

For instance, I cannot reproduce the behavior in [this fixed live example](http://ideone.com/3viU1k).

Comment: Use `g++ -Wall -std=c++11` when compiling to get a warning for this behavior

Comment: And to explain what is probably happening; the compiler sees a control path that flows off the end of the function without returning and concludes that that path can never be taken. On that basis it causes the switch statement to unconditionally take the other path.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an end-of-the-function return statement and a closing curly braces for your switch in the function.

```
int llex(){
    cout<<"enter 1"<<endl;
    char32_t c = U'(';
    cout<<(c==U'#')<<endl;
    switch(c){
    case U'#':
        cout<<"enter 2"<<endl;
        return 5;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```